# GooglePlayServicesClient onConnected callback is called even with no network

Tags: android, google-maps

I am writing an app that uses Google's location services. From what I understand, when I call the `connect()` method on a `LocationClient` object, the object that implements`GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks` is supposed to receive an `onConnected()` callback **only if** the `LocationClient` succeeds in connecting to Google's location services.

The problem, however, is that I receive this callback even if my phone is not connected to the internet. Somehow, the system must think that the `LocationClient` is successfully connecting to Google's location services even though my phone is not connected to the internet.

What gives?

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onConnected` callback method is called when your app successfully connects to Google Play Services application. You don't need to be connected to internet to receive GPS updates.